# Print Maven test results in line with test output

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I find it unhelpful that Maven re-orders the output from my test methods. Is there a way to stop it doing that? For example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

class DemoTest {
    @Test
    void failDemo() {
        System.err.println("This test fails");
        fail();
    }

    @Test
    void passDemo() {
        System.err.println("This test passes");
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
mvn test
...
[INFO] Running DemoTest
This test fails
java.lang.AssertionError
        at DemoTest.failDemo(DemoTest.java:9)
[ERROR] failDemo  Time elapsed: 0.029 s  <<< FAILURE!
This test passes
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.037 s <<< FAILURE! - in DemoTest
```

Actual:

```
mvn test
...
[INFO] Running DemoTest
This test fails
This test passes
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.037 s <<< FAILURE! - in DemoTest
[ERROR] failDemo  Time elapsed: 0.029 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
        at DemoTest.failDemo(DemoTest.java:9)
```

As you can see above, Maven removes the output of all the assertion errors, collects them all and then outputs them at the end, after the totals. I would like instead for Maven not to do that, but leave the output of the assertion errors to go together with the output from each test.

Comment: Can you please post the full test source code?

Comment: @khmarbaise that was almost the full source code - it just needed to be enclosed by a class. Anyway, I've added the full source code now.

Comment: Thanks for the supplemtal information.. Please check version of maven-surefire-plugin you are using. You should use the most recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Within the example you are mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5).

The import `org.junit.Assert` is part of JUnit 4 while the other imports are of JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5).

In general unit tests should never rely on any execution order because they should be independent of the order.

JUnit Jupiter (or more accurately the junit-jupiter-engine) changes the order; More details on that in the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order).

If it is really necessary to have a particular order you can use the `Order` annotation. For example like this (copied from the docs):

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
class OrderedTestsDemo {

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void nullValues() {
        // perform assertions against null values
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void emptyValues() {
        // perform assertions against empty values
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    void validValues() {
        // perform assertions against valid values
    }

}
```

I strongly recommend never to use the order annotation in unit tests. Sometime it's useful using the order annotation for integration tests.

So finally the maven-surefire-plugin or Maven do not change the order of execution order of the tests it's done by the junit-jupiter-engine which is doing that intentionally.

Comment: Thanks. It was by mistake that I used JUnit 4's `fail()`, but even after changing it to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail` I still have the same problem. I don't mind JUnit changing the order of the tests. That's not what I'm asking about. What I want is that when an AssertionError is thrown, the output from the assertion error should appear _in the same test run_ as the output of the test itself. What actually happens is that Maven _removes_ the output of the AssertionError, and then puts the output of all assertions right at the end, after the totals. I don't want that.

Comment: Ah Ok... You should configure maven-surefire-plugin and enhance the configuration with: `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` ... using an older version using most recent version this is already default.

Comment: Thanks, but it still prints the stack trace _after_ all the tests have run, instead of with each test. The only difference now is that it shows the _full_ stack trace instead of only the first few lines.